# vitesse vue3 issue adding libraries

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to add some dependencies to vitesse with vue 3 and typescript. I added a couple of libraries with `pnpm`

```
pnpm add @aws-sdk/credential-providers
pnpm add @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb
```

Now when I try and `pnpm dev` I get the following errors when I hit the route calling the component with the code utilizing the dependencies. I have no idea how to proceed (more of an infrastructure person, this is my first time trying typescript)

```
pnpm dev

> @ dev /Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend
> vite --port 3333 --open

Pre-bundling dependencies:
  vite-ssg
  nprogress
  pinia
  vue-i18n
  vue
  (...and 3 more)
(this will be run only when your dependencies or config have changed)

  vite v2.6.10 dev server running at:

  > Local: http://localhost:3333/
  > Network: use `--host` to expose

  ready in 789ms.

3:56:55 PM [vite] hmr update /src/pages/hi/[name].vue
3:56:55 PM [vite] new dependencies found: @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb, @aws-sdk/credential-providers, updating...
 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-imds@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist-es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js:3:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:buffer" for import "Buffer"
    3 │ import { Buffer } from "buffer";
      ╵          ~~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-imds@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist-es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js:4:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:http" for import "request"
    4 │ import { request } from "http";
      ╵          ~~~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-imds@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist-es/fromContainerMetadata.js:3:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:url" for import "parse"
    3 │ import { parse } from "url";
      ╵          ~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+shared-ini-file-loader@3.37.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader/dist-es/index.js:2:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:fs" for import "readFile"
    2 │ import { readFile } from "fs";
      ╵          ~~~~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+shared-ini-file-loader@3.37.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader/dist-es/index.js:3:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:os" for import "homedir"
    3 │ import { homedir } from "os";
      ╵          ~~~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+shared-ini-file-loader@3.37.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader/dist-es/index.js:4:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:path" for import "join"
    4 │ import { join, sep } from "path";
      ╵          ~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+shared-ini-file-loader@3.37.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/shared-ini-file-loader/dist-es/index.js:4:15: error: No matching export in "browser-external:path" for import "sep"
    4 │ import { join, sep } from "path";
      ╵                ~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-sso@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-sso/dist-es/index.js:6:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:crypto" for import "createHash"
    6 │ import { createHash } from "crypto";
      ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-sso@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-sso/dist-es/index.js:7:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:fs" for import "readFileSync"
    7 │ import { readFileSync } from "fs";
      ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-sso@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-sso/dist-es/index.js:8:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:path" for import "join"
    8 │ import { join } from "path";
      ╵          ~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-ini@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini/dist-es/index.js:5:9: error: No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-web-identity@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-web-identity/dist-es/index.js" for import "fromTokenFile"
    5 │ import { fromTokenFile } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-web-identity";
      ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-process@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-process/dist-es/index.js:4:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:child_process" for import "exec"
    4 │ import { exec } from "child_process";
      ╵          ~~~~

 > node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-providers@3.42.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-providers/dist-es/fromTokenFile.js:3:9: error: No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-web-identity@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-web-identity/dist-es/index.js" for import "fromTokenFile"
    3 │ import { fromTokenFile as _fromTokenFile, } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-web-identity";
      ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

3:56:56 PM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 13 errors:
node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-imds@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist-es/fromContainerMetadata.js:3:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:url" for import "parse"
node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-imds@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist-es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js:3:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:buffer" for import "Buffer"
node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-imds@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist-es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js:4:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:http" for import "request"
node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-ini@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-ini/dist-es/index.js:5:9: error: No matching export in "node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-web-identity@3.41.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-web-identity/dist-es/index.js" for import "fromTokenFile"
node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+credential-provider-process@3.40.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-process/dist-es/index.js:4:9: error: No matching export in "browser-external:child_process" for import "exec"
...
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1493:15)
    at /Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1151:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:941:63)
    at buildResponseToResult (/Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1149:7)
    at /Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1258:14
    at /Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:629:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:726:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/Users/me/code/github/me/app-frontend/node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.13.3/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:596:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
```

Comment: further investigation seems that it's not possible to use the aws sdk and vite https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/2478

Comment: also see the linked note in the vite repo about the problem  https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1374#issuecomment-754820938    which further says because it uses Node stuff it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Since Vite does not wrap NodeJS libraries on its own, core libraries such as buffer, fs, and path are not available for use in the browser. You can find fixes (eg https://github.com/feross/buffer or https://github.com/ionic-team/rollup-plugin-node-polyfills) to help handle these cases.

In my case I only had a problem with the buffer, so I only installed buffer with `npm i buffer -D`